# VSCODE touches file twice when saving

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am experiencing a strange issue in VSCODE. After i save a file i have to press CTRL+Z twice in order to revert the last change. This occurs among all file types, HTML, TypeScript, SCSS, doenst make a difference.

Dont know exactly when it started, but probably after the last update. Not sure.

I am using VSCODE 1.51.1

Would be great if someone can help.

Comment: You can [download 1.50.1](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_50), re-test, and if it's genuinely an issue that was introduced in 1.51.1 then [raise a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9419) from 2016, but it doenst provide a solution

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your suggestion, think i have to try that but i am afraid of loosing my settings

Comment: Not sure why i had that issue and what happened in the meanwhile but the issue is gone... without doing anything

Comment: Still happens for me.